# Retrieving Mysql data fails... Why?

Tags: php, html, mysql, database

So this is my code but it does not work, I just get this

```
Title Article "; while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) { echo ""; echo "" . $row['Title'] . ""; echo "" . $row['Article'] . ""; echo ""; } echo ""; mysqli_close($con); ?>
```

Any ideas?

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","____","____","test_database");
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM written");

echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>Title</th>
<th>Article</th>
</tr>";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['Title'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['Article'] . "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
  }
 echo "</table>";

 mysqli_close($con);
 ?>
```

Comment: Looks like php is not working correct. Try with a file which only calls `phpinfo()`
 if you don't see the whole php configuration php isn't running correct.

Comment: What `wumm` suggested may very well be the cause, that PHP may not be enabled on your server, give that a try with `<?php phpinfo();?>` and see if you get any results. However, if PHP is in fact running, and MySQL is running, then try using this instead `echo '<table border=\"1\"><tr><th>Title</th><th>Article</th></tr>';` and see what you get out of that. I was faced with a similar problem before.

Comment: Strange, I just re-saved a few times, and changed the file from .php to .html just to change it back to .php again; it worked. Thanks for the help though!:)

Comment: Stranger things have happened. @Alex

Answer (score 1):

Tripple check your quotation marks are set correctly. Either

```
echo "<table border='1'>
```

or

```
</tr>";
```

has an error in it.

You may also try using echo as a function (bracelets), it should make spotting the error easier :-)

It would be helpfull to see the resulting markup instead of the text ;-)

Comment: That has nothing to do with. Check the OP's code again, the echo is wrapped inside double quotes, which is perfectly valid, however using single quotes at times helps in some cases. [See OP's comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19774195/retrieving-mysql-data-fails-why#comment29390585_19774195)

Answer (score 0):

You have to do this:

```
echo "<table border='1'><tr><th>Title</th><th>Article</th></tr>";
```

or

```
echo "<table border='1'>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<th>Title</th>";
echo "<th>Article</th>";
echo "</tr>";
```

instead of

```
echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>Title</th>
<th>Article</th>
</tr>";
```